# How can I listen mouse events from d3 when jquery drag & drop is in action?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, event-handling

I'm planning to use jquery to drag dom nodes over svg and drop them so that d3 can handle the drop. [This so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991049/create-a-shape-in-d3-js-by-drag-and-drop-of-a-dom-element) gave me a good starting point.

When I listen to mousemove event from d3, d3 does not seem to properly track mouse move during jquery's drag operation. I'd like to make d3 to respond to drag before drop, and for that I need to track the drag that has been started by jquery outside of svg.

I've modified the fiddle from the question above to demonstrate the approach that is not working. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bAAB2/1/)

here is the code from the fiddle:

```
var treeCreator = function(){}; 


  treeCreator.prototype.callbacktest = function(svgContainer){
  alert('the element has been dropped');
  }; 

  treeCreator.prototype.createTreeNode = function(theSVG){
      $('#tobeDropped').remove();
      theSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke","green")
        .style("fill","white")
        .attr("r",40)
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .on("mouseover", function () {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");
        })
            .on("mouseout", function () {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
        }); 
 }; 

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#tobeDropped').draggable({containment:'#mainContainer'});

var theSVG = d3.select('#dropInSVG')
.append("svg")
.attr("width",200)
.attr("height",200);

var positionLabel = theSVG.append("text")
                .attr("x", 10)
                .attr("y", 30).text("begin log");
 theSVG.on("mousemove", function () {
            var position = d3.mouse(this); 
            positionLabel.text(position);
        });

var tc = new treeCreator(); 

$('#dropInSVG').droppable({
    drop: function(){
        tc.createTreeNode(theSVG); 
    }
});

  });
```

mousemove listener updates the label correctly when jquery drag is not in action, but fails to do so during the drag. it performs some updates but it is unpredictable and incomplete.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

Answer (score -1):

This might me more of a hack than a solution, but you could always listen to [`drag`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)

```
function updatePosition() {
  var position = d3.mouse(theSVG.node()); 
  positionLabel.text(position);
}

var dragging = false; 

$('#tobeDropped').draggable({
  containment: '#mainContainer',
  start:       function() { dragging = true; },
  stop:        function() { dragging = false; },
  drag:        updatePosition
});

theSVG.on("mousemove", function () {
  if (dragging) return; 
  updatePosition();
});
```